# Hibernate Mapping with Spring-Data-JPA

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to use Hibernate Table Per Subclass for a problem I have.   I have a Workday that is used by both an Office and Employee class.

```
@Table(name="WorkDay")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class AbstractWorkday {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Long workdayId;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private boolean active;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private DayOfWeek dayOfWeek;

    @Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentLocalTime")
    private LocalTime startTime;

    @Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentLocalTime")
    private LocalTime endTime;

    @Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentLocalTime")
    private LocalTime breakStartTime;

    @Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentLocalTime")
    private LocalTime breakEndTime;
//getters and setters
}
```

and then two inherited classes that are specific to Office and Employee

```
@Entity
@Table(name="EMPLOYEEWORKDAY")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="workday_id")
public class EmployeeWorkday extends AbstractWorkday {

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "employeeId", nullable = false)
    private Employee employee;
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name="OFFICEWORKDAY")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="workday_id")
public class OfficeWorkday extends AbstractWorkday {

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "officeId", nullable = false)
    private Office office;
```

I then use each one as:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EMPLOYEE")
public class Employee {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long employeeId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "officeId", nullable = false)
    private Office office;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "employee", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch =    FetchType.EAGER)
    @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    List<EmployeeWorkday> workDays = new ArrayList<EmployeeWorkday>(); 
...
}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "OFFICE")
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "officeId")
public class Office {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long officeId;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "office", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    private List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<Employee>();

     @OneToMany(mappedBy = "office", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    List<OfficeWorkday> workDays = new ArrayList<OfficeWorkday>();
```

The problem I am trying to solve is that both Office and Employee have Workdays. But since I have a bi-directional mapping between them all, it seems better to break the Workdays into different types.

However, this "feels" wrong.  I am trying to do multi-tenant, so that employees and workdays can be isolated by office.  But this seems convoluted and I am constantly chasing down hibernate issues, like when I do a findOffice, I get the correct office with its Workdays, and then the correct Employees, but their workdays are null - even though I saw them persisted.

Can anyone identify this code smell and the best solution for it ?

Comment: With Spring v4.1.4, Spring Data JPA v1.7.1 and Hibernate v4.3.7, I could not get the code to work.  On starting the app, Spring bails out with the exception `Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: OfficeDay`.  Replacing `@Table` on `AbstractWorkday` with `@MappedSuperclass` worked fine and the application ran as expected.  You can check my code on [Github](https://github.com/manish-in-java/spring-data-inheritance).  What are your dependency versions?

Comment: I would also like to say that Employee-to-Office relationship should be many-to-many instead of many-to-one since many companies have employees working from different offices (support staff, shared service functions, etc.).